# ¿Hacer que se actualicen los estilos css?

Tags: php, css3

Hola amigos resulta que a veces aplico css a mis archivos php pero una vez actualizo la pagina lo que yo actualizo de php se refleja pero lo relacionado con css no. Qué puedo hacer al respecto?

Comment: mira [ask] y mejora tu redacción; explica que no funciona colocando un ejemplo

Comment: además los estilos css los interpreta el navegador, no tiene nada que ver con tu servidor wamp

Comment: Hola. Q a veces aplico estilos css a archivos php pero cuando recargo la página no los lee sino que para ver los cambios toca salirse del servidor y volver a entrar.

Comment: intenta con CTRL+SHIFT+R, esto sirve para refrescar la pagina por completo

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigos estuve buscando en google y me funciono hacer esto despues de la ruta de los estilos:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" />
<script src="/js/functions.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza la pagina con CTRL+F5, luego de un cambio. Cache suele hacer esas cosas.

Una forma de evitar eso es programar con llamadas a los .css con parametros. por ejemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/ec_nominas.css?version=1.x.x">
```

cuando publicas la aplicacion la version cambiara (obviamente 1.x.x es una variable), pero en desarrollo es mejor y mas rapido recargar la pagina limpiando el cache) (con ctrol+f5, o pulsar en refresh con el click secundario y cargar la pag. de manera forzada)

Comment: pero esto lo va a tener que hacer cada vez que accede a su sitio, es buena opción?

Comment: no shadow otra vez! No era la pregunta, Obviamente esta desarrollando no en produccion. Hay otras formas, pero no pregunto eso.

Comment: Esto es muy complicado para mi. Pido disculpas pero no tengo tanto tiempo para estudiar tantas reglas. Como elimino mi cuenta?

Comment: no la elimines, solo considera que los aportes que se hagan no van solo enfocados a quien pregunta sino a una larga lista de usuarios que con el tiempo vendrán buscando una respuesta similar algunos con mas experiencia, otros mas novatos; entonces leer las reglas es simple amigo mira [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Forzar al navegador a descargar ficheros que podría tener en cache, va a repercutir siempre en la velocidad de carga de la página, lo cual perjudica la experiencia de usuario.

Muchas veces, de hecho la mayoría de las veces, no hay cambios sobre esos fichero por lo tanto lo más optimo sería recargarlos solo cuando sea necesario.

Una manera fácil de controlar cuando forzar la recarga, es usa una variable bajo nuestro control en vez de la función `time()`. Por ejemplo podríamos usar la variable `$version`.

Por lo tanto, cuando en alguno de los fichero de configuración, establezcamos la variable `$versión` con un valor diferente al actual, el navegador volverá a descargar los ficheros, pero mientras `$version`no varíe, los podrá usar desde la caché.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css?v=<?= $version ?>" />
<script src="/js/functions.js?v=<?= $version ?>"></script>
```

Esto mismo lo podemos usar para imágenes o cualquier otro elemento de pueda ser cacheado.

```
<img src="img/cabecera.png?v=?>=$version?>" />
```

Para el navegador el nombre de la imagen será diferente y esto hará que la vuelva a descargar, en vez de usar la versión en caché.

Para lo que si va realmente bien usar una variable tipo `time()` es para las llamadas ajax si el framework no lo implementa ya de serie.